# volatile array and locality of reference

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile, cpu-cache

Locality of reference .http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference. 
So its like iterating a small int array would be faster then iterating a linkedList.
Because array is contiguous and all the array could be fit in the cpu cache and there 
would be less cache misses.

But i want a comparison between a simple int array and a volatile array. AFAIK iterating over a volatile array would result in a volatile read every time which may in some system result 
in updating cache on every read.

```
int[] arr; // assume here i have declared and initialized it.
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    sum = sum + arr[i];
}
```

volatile counter part

```
volatile int[] arr; // assume here i have declared and initialized it.
int sum = 0;
for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    sum = sum + arr[i]; // volatile read everytime
}
```

So would they be same or compiler would make all the volatile reads into a single volatile read( compiler optimization)

Comment: Have you tried comparing the generated bytecode? That's generally a good starting point when asking about (non-JIT) compiler optimizations.

Comment: I'm a little confused about what you are trying to do. `int arr;` does not initialize an array. Moreover this correct code: `volatile int[] arr = new int[len];` will not initialize an array with volatile elements. Only a volatile reference to the array. http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2009/06/volatile-arrays-in-java.html

Comment: Hi yahh i know.. i said assume they are initialized there ..don't wanted to write the code:). Second i know its a volatile to reference to array therefore its a volatile reas every time you do this arr[i] .. because it first read the array and the corresponding position

Answer (score 3):

If you need a volatile access to an array you can use [AtomicIntegerArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicIntegerArray.html).  This wraps an `int` array but gives thread safe semantics.

```
AtomicIntegerArray array = new AtomicIntegerArray(100);
array.addAndGet(1);
array.lazySet(10, 123);
int n = array.get(5); // volatile get
array.set(9, 333); // volatile set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight improvement to Scientist's code: You don't actually need an additional volatile boolean flag, you can get by with just the following:

```
volatile int[] array = ...;

void write(int index, int value){
    array[index]=value;
    array = array; // explicit volatile write
}

int read(int index){
    return array[index]; // implicit volatile read
}
```

The major change is that you don't need an additional read of a volatile variable for the read, since accessing the ith element of an array involves reading the volatile reference to the array (whether the JIT/compiler actually does is a different thing, but it has to give you the same guarantees). So that's quite nice as it's exactly the code you'd write anyhow. 
Sadly that doesn't work for writes to the array so you have to do this really ugly self-assignment.

That said the AtomicIntegerArray class is just as efficient (you'd hope so at least) as this and makes the whole thing explicit.